# PHP returns blank with legit code

Tags: php, facebook

I've copy pasted the get facebook messages script from this website:
http://cappelendesign.no/2010/04/tutorial-facebook-rss-feed-parser-in-pure-php/

Works like a charm on two test hosts but I can't determine why it doesn't on the main..

PHP Version is 5.3.15
And SimpleXML is enabled.

I've tryed different retrieve PHP scripts from whom I know they work. They all return blank.

Any ideas on what this problem could be?

Gr.
Kevin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usually happens when you have an error but the php is defined not to show errors.

try to add:

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

at the begin of your code to see the errors.

Comment: Thx, it indeed did return an error. (Warning: simplexml_load_file(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0)

Comment: try to add `ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 'on');` if it works add it to your php.ini (don't forget to reload apache after)

Comment: I don't have the rights to do that but I called my hosting company to fix it :)